# Check if iPhone is trying to connect to internet

Tags: iphone

I want to know if my device is trying to connect to internet eventhough my application is in background or closed. Even if any other application is trying to connect to internet.

I read in a blog that we can register for local notifications, though no sample code was provided for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mantra :** You can not measure or manipulate outside your own application, unless a open framework exists. And those are few.

Measuring packages sent and received are both outside the "quarantine-zone" of the Apple Developer Guidelines, and therefor **not** allowed.

If you DO happen to find some tricky way to do this (that is, the private iOS frameworks) you must know that your app will never be approved.

The closest thing that comes to this was the talk about a statistics API, where apps could see the number of calls made, data transferred, etc.
But this was not very well looked upon by the approval board, and will probably not be a reality any time soon.